# Delete extra spaces in list items - Sublime Text 2

Tags: list, keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext2, spaces

[image: Example:]

Sometimes I need to put tags at the end of a list item using the shortcut: [Ctr] + [Shift] + [L] + [End] to edit multiple list items using multiple cursors. This doesn't always work so well when there are extra spaces at the end of a list item, making tha actual end of the item a few spaces longer than the text of the item.

Is there a shortcut I can use along with [Ctr] + [Shift] + [L] to delete those extra spaces and essentially make the "end" where the text ends?

Please ask questions if you need clarification on my question and I will try to best make it most clear.

Comment: Could you add an example?  I don't understand why there are spaces after the last text of a line.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found shortcuts for this. So I wrote one. It will trim the trailing white spaces of the current line. For example, after you enter `ctrl+shift+l`, you find that there are extra white spaces, enter `ctrl+f` and then `ctrl+t` to delete them. White spaces in other line won't be affected.

Key mapping:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+f", "ctrl+t"], "command": "delete_trailing_white_space" }
```

delete_trailing_white_space.py (put it `Sublime Text 2\Packages\User`)

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

class DeleteTrailingWhiteSpaceCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        for region in self.view.sel():
            line = self.view.line(region)
            line_content = self.view.substr(line)
            trimed_line = line_content.rstrip()
            self.view.replace(edit, line, trimed_line)
```

Comment: That's great, I think I understans remotely what your trying to do. I'm not very savvy with saving to SublimeText2\Packages\User. How is this done?

Comment: So you do not want to add a new plugin to `SublimeText2\Packages\User` or you do not want any plugin?

Comment: For how to create a Sublime Text 2 plugin, please refer to http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/python-tutorials/how-to-create-a-sublime-text-2-plugin/.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to delete the spaces, you can rebind the end key to a plugin that modifies the behavior. I wrote this when I was playing around with some virtual white space stuff, so it's only minimally tested ([link](https://gist.github.com/skuroda/5177615)). Save it to `Packages/User`. The name of the file doesn't matter, just make sure it has the `.py` extension. Then, add the following as a custom key binding.

```
{
    "keys": ["end"], "command": "custom_move_to_end_line"                              
}
```